# Make GridLayout in Android behave like ordinary Java

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android app with the `GridLayout`. I am not using XML because it will be a dynamic UI changing with user input so I need to add and remove components on the fly. In this case I am putting buttons on a grid layout and I want the buttons in the grid span the entire.

In normal Java I would write like this

```
public class Grids extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Grids g=new Grids();
        g.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Grids()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(500, 300, 240, 400);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        add(new JButton("A"));
        add(new JButton("B"));
        add(new JButton("C"));
        add(new JButton("D"));
        add(new JButton("E"));
        //add(new JButton("6"));
    }
}
```

As far as I could figure, this is the way to write it for Android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private GridLayout root;
    private Button a, b, c, d, e;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        root = new GridLayout(this);
        root.setRowCount(3);
        root.setColumnCount(2);

        a=new Button(this);
        b=new Button(this);
        c=new Button(this);
        d=new Button(this);
        e=new Button(this);

        a.setText("A");
        b.setText("B");
        c.setText("C");
        d.setText("D");
        e.setText("E");

        root.addView(a);
        root.addView(b);
        root.addView(c);
        root.addView(d);
        root.addView(e);

        this.setContentView(root);
    }
}
```

But it does not work the way I expected it to. The image below illustrates my problem. I need the buttons in Android to span the entire phone screen. This UI changes on the fly so in this case I think it is better to not use XML.

Image link

[image]

I am not allowed po post images yet so you need to open it manually.

Comment: it is the default behaviour. What you could do is to retrieve the screen width and divide it for the numbers of column. This way you should know how big the child should be - in width term, at least -

Answer (score 0):

You have to use fill_parent both in gridView and button views.

By default you have wrap_content - what you can see on your screenshot.

It's not possible to use smth like this:

```
setBounds(500, 300, 240, 400);
```

Because you don't know the physical device's dimensions and you couldn't normally run apps in window mode.

Comment: The size of the window do not affect the behaviour of the GridLayout.

Comment: Follow-up question. How do I set fill_parent without using XML?

Comment: You can create you own LayourParams, and this class has 2 params - width and height, you could use LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT for example. Be carefull, each ViewGroup has it's own params like LinearLayout.LayouParams etc.